# AWS Beanstalk Deploy Laravel with Grunt Tasks

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, gruntjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Laravel 4.1 App that I want to run on a AWS Beanstalk.
But the thing is I have some Grunt tasks that I want to run on deploy to compile less files and RequireJS Optimize and do a `bower install`

The thing is that this is a AWS Beanstalk PHP Instance. So, I think it doesn't have nodejs installed to run this tasks.

Any ideas how can I deal with this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up building the entire assets in a bundle before deploying. Then detecting the environment and pointing to that `production bundle` instead of building it in the server. That in the end is not right.